# Intel iGPU die area and power consumption

Tags: cpu, intel, gpu

What is the Intel's iGPU area occupied on the die (or transistor count) and what is the power consumpition of the iGPU alone?
Didnt find any information from Intel, quite odd they dont advertise this information in the spec sheet.

Comment: some are really large, when I was researching my XEON 1245v3 I member the GPU is about twice the size of 4 CPU cores

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about existing chips, not electronics design.

Comment: @user3528438 interesting input. do you remember where did you find it?

Comment: @BrianCarlton, whats wrong with design (it is design question) of existing circuitry?

Comment: here, https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-graphics-developers-guides, I used to read "Gen7.5 compute architecture" and there are a lot of interesting picture in it, and the whole thing is a interesting read if you are interested in computer architecture.

Comment: @user3528438 Great article. Thanks! Would you like to make it an answer?

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely a secret. They publish these photo's in their press kit:

[image: Intel Core i7-2600K die photo]
(Intel Core i7-2600K source: [pcmag](http://au.pcmag.com/chipsets-processors-products/22179/gallery/intel-core-i7-2600k?p=2))

And, since all parts of a family have the same die, you can read the specs to see the changes.
For example, if you compare these two chips: [E3-1226V3 and E3-1230 v3](https://ark.intel.com/compare/80917,75054).
You will see that graphics come at the expense of hyperthreading and still costs 4 watts more.

It's also completely irrelevant data if you're not developing motherboards. That's why they do not publish it to the end user.
Intel does publish register maps, for those wanting to program bare metal. But designing a board for these parts is such an effort that you **have to** ask Intel for design assistance.

Comment: looks like the iGPU is the same size as four cores, kinda contradicts @user3528438 findings. Does the iGPU rectangle includes 128mb of on-die graphic memory? Regarding the power consumption, could you estimate how much power can be saved when disabling the hyper-threading? without that figure additional 4 watts mean nothing

Comment: @kreuzerkrieg The on-chip vram would be the upper top part of the gpu part I guess. Looks similar to the L3 cache.

Comment: @kreuzerkrieg, you did not specify any core, therefore there is no contradiction here.